# Suppress pop up "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer"

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I've implemented a new Group Policy infrastructure at a school. I'm at the final stages of tidy up before go live next week but there is one thing thats got me stuck.

As expected I've locked the students out of most of the fun stuff, but when they try to do something I have restricted (WIN+R) for example, they get the pop up message:

```
"This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator"
```

Which is expected behaviour as I *have* restricted that operation.

However I'd like it to just silently not do anything rather than pop this up (with associated annoying beep that I can imagine kids abusing).

All client machines are on Windows 7, DC is 2008 R2. Domain functional level is *ahem* Windows 2000 (which is on the to-do list before you say anything).

Any thoughts on how to supress this warning?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to suppress the message and you probably really don't want to. The message provides feedback to the user regarding the action they're attempting. If they didn't get feedback you'd be inundated with support calls like "I clicked suchandsuch but nothing happens", and "I can't access suchandsuch", and "Why doesn't suchandsuch work?".

Comment: These are children on highly restricted classroom PC's. As long as they can open their software packages thats all they ever need to do. If this was corporate world I would agree with you (although, I wouldn't lock the machines down so hard so it wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: Has no one found an answer for this? By right clicking on the error message in the task bar I am able to launch Windows Explorer. I have completely disabled right clicking on everything and I am still able to launch Windows Explorer from that pop up message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly - this isn't likely to be an issue. I've seen hundreds (And I mean that literally) of school IT setups - they all have these messages and it's simply just part of the system. You're doing the right things and as @joeqwerty says - it provides feedback to the user that they've been deliberately prevented from doing something.

If it's possible to suppress it, then it's a configuration I've *never* seen, so is almost certainly unsupported at best and unstable at worst.